# Use Samba AD DC as Password Backend for Samba PDC

Tags: active-directory, samba, domain-controller, samba4, smb-conf

I've got the following situation:

- Old Samba-server `data.company.com` Version 4.6.7
- Configured as a PDC with `workgroup = COMPANY` for a population of Windows hosts with the following configuration:

```
[global]
        workgroup = COMPANY
        server string = COMPANY Samba Server
        netbios name = SMBMASTER
        unix extensions = no
        max open files = 200000
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        #log level = 9
        ntlm auth = Yes
        security = user
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        domain master = yes
        domain logons = yes
        logon path =
        logon script = logon.bat
        logon drive = U:
        local master = yes
        wins support = yes
```

- New Samba-server `dc1.company.com` Version 4.17.4
- Configured as an AD DC with `workgroup = COMPANY-NEW` the following configuration:

```
[global]
        dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
        netbios name = DC1
        realm = COMPANY-NEW.COMPANY.INTERNAL
        server role = active directory domain controller
        workgroup = COMPANY-NEW
        log level = 2
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
        min protocol = SMB2
        ntlm auth = yes
        ldap server require strong auth = no

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/company-new.company.internal/scripts
        read only = No
```

Machines can join fine to both domains, `COMPANY` and `COMPANY-NEW` and, once joined, update their passwords (with Ctrl+Alt+Del in Windows) on the respective domain.

What I would like to achieve is for the old server to use the new server for authentication of the users (as a password backend) so users don't have two passwords. This way, I could slowly migrate the population from the old domain to the new and no matter where a user changes their password, they would implicitly change it for both domains.

Since I cannot join the old server `data.company.com` to the new server `dc1.company.com` because they have different domain names, I tried out setting the LDAP-server of the new server as a passdb backend for the old one as follows:

```
[global]
        workgroup = COMPANY
        server string = COMPANY Samba Server
        netbios name = SMBMASTER
        unix extensions = no
        max open files = 200000
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        #log level = 9
        ntlm auth = Yes
        security = user
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        domain master = yes
        domain logons = yes
        logon path =
        logon script = logon.bat
        logon drive = U:
        local master = yes
        wins support = yes
        passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://dc1.company.com
        ldapsam:editposix = yes
        ldapsam:trusted = yes
        ldap admin dn = cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal
        ldap suffix = dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal
        ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
        ldap machine suffix = ou=Computers
        ldap user suffix = ou=Users
        ldap ssl = off
        idmap config * : backend = autorid
        idmap config * : range = 10000-24999999
        idmap config COMPANY: backend = ldap
        idmap config COMPANY: range = 10000-19999
        idmap config COMPANY: ldap_base_dn = ou=idmap,dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal
        idmap config COMPANY: ldap_user_dn = cn=admin,dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal
        map untrusted to domain = yes
        ldap delete dn = yes
        ldap password sync = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
```

With this change however, my old server won't start anymore and give me the following message in the logs:

```
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.778601,  3] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1743(main)
  Becoming a daemon.
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.781838,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:161(make_pdb_method_name)
  No builtin backend found, trying to load plugin
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.786133,  2] ../lib/util/modules.c:196(do_smb_load_module)
  Module 'ldapsam' loaded
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.786281,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:280(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Searching for:[(&(objectClass=sambaDomain)(sambaDomainName=COMPANY))]
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.800342,  2] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:794(smbldap_open_connection)
  smbldap_open_connection: connection opened
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.853302,  3] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1013(smbldap_connect_system)
  ldap_connect_system: successful connection to the LDAP server
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.853352,  4] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1092(smbldap_open)
  The LDAP server is successfully connected
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.895873,  3] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:305(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Got no domain info entries for domain
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.934623,  3] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:166(add_new_domain_info)
  add_new_domain_info: Adding new domain
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.936770,  1] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:236(add_new_domain_info)
  add_new_domain_info: failed to add domain dn= sambaDomainName=COMPANY,dc=company-new,dc=company,dc=internal with: No such attribute
        0000200A: objectclass sambaDomain is not a valid objectClass in schema
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.936814,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:313(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Adding domain info for COMPANY failed with NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.936896,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap.c:6540(pdb_ldapsam_init_common)
  pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably without it.
[2023/12/05 19:31:43.936937,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:180(make_pdb_method_name)
  pdb backend ldapsam:ldap://dc1.company.com did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)
```

- Could somebody decipher this for me?
- I my idea even remotely going into the right direction for what I'm trying to achieve?
- If so, where is the mistake in my configuration?
- If not, what would be the right approach?

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm going bonkers over this. If you need more details about my setup or higher log level outputs I'm happy to provide you with them.

Comment: `going into the right direction?` no this is not the right direction. The strategy is convoluted and incoherent. This is something that is normally quick and easy but multiple approaches for implementation and administration have been defeated. And it involves tinkering with a release that was End Of Life five years ago, and a "new" server using a release that will be EOL in four months...

Comment: Thanks for answering, @GregAskew . Would you mind going into details on my followup question, i.e. `If not, what would be the right approach?`? The whole point is to get rid of the "old" server and get the "new" server up and running which we will then be able to continuously upgrade. So what is the right direction in your humble opinion? Do you have any actual advice for me?